# Getting Wireless on a MacbookPro4,1

Tags: wireless, mac

I just put Ubuntu on my MacbookPro4,1, but I can't find or connect to any wireless networks. I've tried installing drivers from System -> Administration -> Hardware Drivers, as well as manually patching (per [this site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBook4-1/Lucid#AirPort)).

All my hardware is standard, what came with the machine.

Comment: After some trouble with Flash Player, I think I'm just going to reinstall 32-bit and try again, since I was trying be cool and go 64.  I can't seem to delete it, sorry for the hassle :/

Comment: You might look at my similar question about wireless problems - http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/4266/unable-to-connect-to-wireless-network - Using the information I got back from the command line, I was able to determine that there is a general problem with my wireless card and when I googled for my actual wireless card, I found several walk-throughs on how to fix them.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete Ubuntu 64bit, just start from the live CD and open GParted from system-administration. Of-cause you should backup your home folder.
It is possible that your wireless card is only supported in 32bit.